# Its possible for RXJS Observers create Context, as in React?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6

Hy, im new in Rxjs..

React have its [React context](http://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). Similar is possible with Rxjs? My goal is create property, which is accessible from rxjs operators with `this`...

```
const myObserver = Observable.create(function(observer) {
  Object.defineProperty(observer, "context", {
    value: {test: 'test'},
    writable: false
  });
  observer.next(data);
  observer.complete();
});

myObserver.pipe(map(function(data){
// this.context === {test: 'test'} //true
 return data
}))
```

Comment: No. Each operator will have it's own `Subscriber`, which will be passed as the `this` context to some - but not all - operator callback functions.